# Free up memory from WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

We have a complex winforms application and the issue is that on every new form we open,
(example open Form A->

```
FormA f = new FormA();
f.Show();
```

) memory usage grows.
That is understandable , but when we close that (form A - Close()) memory usage stays on that point (high). And after some times of opening new forms and closing, memory raises more and leads to app crash (application closes).

I have tried using Dispose() , GC but none of them seems to work.
Is there anyway to clear the memory used by form A when closing (form A) ?

Comment: Dispose is the way to go. The rest should be left to the GC. IF you still have problems then use a profiler to find out whats actually holding on memory.

Comment: Please share what exactly you've tried. As Ralf mentioned, `Dispose` is what you need, so we are pretty interested in how that failed your expactations.

Comment: If you create graphic objects in that Form and you don't explicitly dispose of those objects, the memory usage will increase non-stop. As mentioned, dispose of the disposable objects you create. When possible, declare those objects with `using` statements -- You should describe what that Form is doing

Answer (score -1):

Actually `this.close` just hides the form and even sometimes you can see the project is still running in the background (The visual studio won't cease compiling and the program is visible in TaskManager).
To collapse it from memory you'd use `Dispose();` to delete from memory!